# Component/software recommendation?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, form

I want to know if you guys know of any good components or extensions which can perform the following:

I want a user to be able to submit a form, view this form and edit it when they require. Every time the form is updated, an email is sent to whoever you added as a CC/email address.

Think of this as a courier process. So there will be steps which I can change from "Pending" to "Shipped", "At courier facility" etc.

Comment: Any form that allows for editing is likely going to require a user account on the site. Take a look at Breezing forms, I suspect it can do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Forms Extensions**

Many of the forms extensions can help with redisplaying and editing submitted data.

ChronoForms can certainly do this. RSForm! Pro can probably do this also.

Forms extensions in the JED are at: https://extensions.joomla.org/category/contacts-and-feedback/forms

**Specific Extension**

[JB Logistic](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/vertical-markets/jb-logistic) is not free but may be able to do some or all of what you are after.